# setDefaultCredential not working for UIWebView in iOS 7 but works fine in earlier iOS versions

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am currently using the following code to set default credentials for UIWebView.  This works fine in iOS 6.1 and earlier.  However, in iOS 7 Beta 6 it does not work at all.

The web pages that I am trying to load use Windows Authentication.  I am able to open them in Safari in iOS 7. However, when I run the below code and then open the URL in a UIWebView, I get an empty white rectangle and nothing ever loads!  Like I said, this works perfectly in iOS 6.1 and earlier.

I also tried a second approach that involves using NSURLConnectionDelegate to hand off the credentials.  This second approach also works fine in iOS 6.1 and earlier, but is broken in iOS 7.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Similar experiences?  Thoughts?

```
// Authenticate
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myusername"
                                                         password:@"mypassword"
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost:@"mysite.com"
                                         port:80
                                         protocol:@"http"
                                         realm:nil
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the question in the Apple developer forums about iOS7?

Comment: Yes - so far no replies

Comment: We have a similar problem with MPMoviePlayer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same exact issue - an NSURLConnection to a Sharepoint site configured for Windows Authentication was working fine in iOS 6.1. In iOS 7 - regardless of whether I targeted and built the app for 6 or 7 - all authentications would seem to succeed (receiving the proper cookie) but still respond with a 401; all subsequent requests sent with the cookie would receive 401 as well.

I resolved the issue by dumping the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate protocol in favor of willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge. Implementing the 2nd delegate protocol means the first never gets called.

In your delegate, implement this delegate protocol:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)sender willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
   if ([challenge previousFailureCount] > 0]) {
       [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
   }else{
      NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLPersistenceForSession];
   [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
   }
}
```

After I implemented this on a whim, my iOS 7 NTLM authentication issues disappeared.

Comment: I have something similar but more complicated because there are multiple different ways I need to authenticate.  Authentication was working in iOS 6 or 7, however this more simple block was useful when the app hit a certain amount of NSURLConnections.  In my case I'm consuming a ton of web services and some were working and some weren't so I was getting the 401 in didReceiveData.  Strange bug..seems like once you hit a certain number of connections, the session just closes and the server loses the credential.

Comment: this will cause a huge amount of connection pooling on your server if you have to put this in a ton of willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge while using NSURLPersistenceForSession and you might not be able to log in or get data until the pool drains..use NSURLPersistenceNone if you have to do this more than once

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** This issue *appears* to be fixed in iOS 7.0.3

I answered this in the Apple developer forum, but now that iOS7 is out of beta, I'll repost here. Currently Windows Authentication is broken in iOS7. I expect there will be a fix out shortly, but until then you can work around the problem by handling authentication challenges in your UIViewController that contains your UIWebView.

Essentially you

1. Make an NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection yourself
2. Handle the connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
3. In the connection:didReceivedResponse manually load your data into the UIWebView

Below I'm loading a PDF, but the process works the same whatever your content type.

```
//Make sure you implement NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate in your header

@interface MyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *conn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *pdfData;
@end

@implementation MyViewController 


//... all of your init and other standard UIViewController methods here...


//Method that loads UIWebview. You'll probably call this in viewDidLoad or somewhere similar... 
- (void) loadWebView {

    //Make Request manually with an NSURLConnection... 
    NSString *url = //Get your url
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    self.conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

//#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate

//Handle authentication challenge (NSURLConnectionDelegate)
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {

        NSString *username = //Get username
        NSString *password = //Get password

        //Use credentials to authenticate
        NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    } else {

        //Cancel authentication & connection
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        [self.conn cancel];
        self.conn = nil;
    }
}

//#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

//Received response (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate)
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    //Init data
    self.pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
}

//Collect data as it comes in (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate)
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.pdfData appendData:data];
}

//Handle connection failure (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate)
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    //Clean up... 
    [self.conn cancel];
    self.conn = nil;
    self.pdfData = nil;

    //TODO: Notify user and offer next step...
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    //Finally, load data into UIWebview here (I'm loading a PDF)...
    [self.webView loadData:self.pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
}


@end
```

Comment: It is utterly unacceptable that Apple let bugs like these slip through testing (2nd time this has happened).  It makes the iPad unusable in Microsoft enterprise environments.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! But I guess that it wont works with redirect?

Comment: @NLemay Redirects shouldn't be a problem. You should just be prepared to handle them if you expect them. See the `connection:didReceiveResponse` and `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse` methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I tried exactly the same but for some reason it is not working